# Linux VPS getting ERROR 2002 when attempting to connect to MySQL service

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, vps

I am trying to set up SQL on my VPS which is running Kali (Debian) When I run any of the commands I am getting these errors below:

```
root@kali:~# sudo service mysql restart
Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.

root@kali:~# sudo mysql stop
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

I have tried rebooting the system but I get the same errors. I have tried re-installing the MySQL but I get this error:

```
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

I have tried to log into the MySQL with my node password and a blank password (since this is a first time access) but I am hit with the same error 2002:

```
root@kali:~# sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

I am running the VPS on my own network that is port forwarded and is a R-Pi 3 with Kali running on it.

Update: If I list directory inside of my `/var/run` directory I see this:

```
root@kali:~# cd /var/run
root@kali:/var/run# ls
NetworkManager     lightdm             openvpn-client   sshd.pid
agetty.reload      lightdm.pid         openvpn-server   sudo
console-setup      lock                pcscd            systemd
crond.pid          log                 postgresql       tmpfiles.d
crond.reboot       mlocate.daily.lock  samba            udev
dbus               motd.dynamic        screen           user
dhclient-eth0.pid  mount               sendsigs.omit.d  utmp
dhclient.eth0.pid  network             shm
initctl            openvpn             sshd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1202978/installing-mysql-server-in-kali-linux) question says `mysql` should be installed on Kali by default. Unless you deliberately removed it, what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

You are using different methods to manage mysql: (1) obviously don't have a service called "mysql.service", hence you cannot start it. (2) Then you try to stop using `sudo mysql stop`, obviously you cannot stop it if not started in the first place.

What does `sudo mysql start` do?

Comment: It is a compact version for R-Pi, when I execute sudo mysql start I get the ERROR 2002